# Fatal error al instalar Magento 2.4.2, Class locale not found ../DataBundle.php:64

Tags: magento2, magento

estoy instalando Magento 2.4.1. Para hacerlo corro en la consola lo siguiente:

php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://localhost/nombreCarpeta/" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="nombreBD" --db-user="root" --db-password="" --admin-firstname="admin" --admin-lastname="admin" --admin-email="admin@mail.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="YOUR PASS HERE" --backend-frontname="admin" --language="en_US" --currency="USD" --timezone="America/Chicago" --use-rewrites="1"

Pero me encuentro en consola con el siguiente error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Locale' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\nombreCarpeta\vendor\magento\framework\Locale\Bundle\DataBundle.php:64
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\nombreCarpeta\vendor\magento\framework\Locale\Bundle\DataBundle.php(28): Magento\Framework\Locale\Bundle\DataBundle->cleanLocale('en_US')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\nombreCarpeta\vendor\magento\framework\Setup\Lists.php(96): Magento\Framework\Locale\Bundle\DataBundle->get('en_US')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\nombreCarpeta\vendor\magento\framework\Validator\Locale.php(42): Magento\Framework\Setup\Lists->getLocaleList()
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\nombreCarpeta\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\InstallStoreConfigurationCommand.php(321): Magento\Framework\Validator\Locale->isValid('en_US')
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\nombreCarpeta\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\InstallStoreConfigurationCommand.php(241): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\InstallStoreConfigurationCommand->validateCodes(Object(Magento\Framework\Validator\Locale), 'en_US', 'language')
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\nombreCarpeta\se in C:\xampp\htdocs\nombreCarpeta\vendor\magento\framework\Locale\Bundle\DataBundle.php on line 64

Como se soluciona? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Ya pude resolver el problema. Faltaba permitir el "intl extension". Para hacerlo miré el siguiente video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cFJVokiDhzk